# Table with Column Hide

Tags: html, jquery, css

Currently my table is scrolling to the right side. I just want the other column to hide just like on the image below using jQuery. Can anyone help me with this?

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Thank you also please see this video for more reference https://www.screencast.com/t/UUvCsMNF9HZ really need your help. Thanks again guys.

Comment: That's no small task.  What plugin was used for the video?   [tag:datatables]?

Comment: No, not how you created the video...  how does the existing table do this?

Comment: I just show it here https://phppot.com/demo/responsive-datatables-with-automatic-column-hiding/

Comment: is there a way to do this on jQuery? I'm also searching how to do this

Comment: Why not follow the tutorial on the page you linked to?   https://phppot.com/jquery/responsive-datatables-with-automatic-column-hiding/

Comment: Your source uses a plugin called [tag:datables] which has a (relatively) simple option to enable this with an option of `"responsive": true,`.   See also: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/init#Option

Comment: Best way to do this is make an hidden element with the dropdown in the item itself. then with jquery the onlything you have to do is put a onclick() on the button to for instance make the element appear.

Comment: yes, it uses the plugin. But is there a way in jQuery? But I'm still looking if theres a way. Thank you for the idea both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false
} );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Responsive Table</h2>          
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" id="demo">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Median Age</th>
            <th>Area (Km²)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Argentina</td>
            <td>Spanish (official), English, Italian, German, French</td>
            <td>41,803,125</td>
            <td>31.3</td>
            <td>2,780,387</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Australia</td>
            <td>English 79%, native and other languages</td>
            <td>23,630,169</td>
            <td>37.3</td>
            <td>7,739,983</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Greece</td>
            <td>Greek 99% (official), English, French</td>
            <td>11,128,404</td>
            <td>43.2</td>
            <td>131,956</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Luxembourg</td>
            <td>Luxermbourgish (national) French, German (both administrative)</td>
            <td>536,761</td>
            <td>39.1</td>
            <td>2,586</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russia</td>
            <td>Russian, others</td>
            <td>142,467,651</td>
            <td>38.4</td>
            <td>17,076,310</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>Swedish, small Sami- and Finnish-speaking minorities</td>
            <td>9,631,261</td>
            <td>41.1</td>
            <td>449,954</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```